# httpListener server (throttling)

Tags: c#

Я делаю сервер httplistener. Он должен выдерживать высокие нагрузки.

У меня есть две функции. Они работают как параллельные потоки. Это попытка создать дросселирование с использованием очереди (throttling)

```
private void Listen()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (listener.IsListening)
                {
                    var context = listener.GetContext();
                    if (queueListenerContext.Count() > requestBound)
                    {
                        SetListenerContextError(context, (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queueListenerContext.Enqueue(context);
                    }
                }
                else Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
        }
    }
}

private void RequestQueue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (queueListenerContext.TryDequeue(out HttpListenerContext listenerContext) && taskCount < taskBound)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref taskCount);
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    HandleContextAsync(listenerContext);
                }).ContinueWith(_ => Interlocked.Decrement(ref taskCount));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Эта функция должна быть завершена через 1 секунду, с того момента, как она начнется

```
private void HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{
   var canceletionToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
   canseletionToken.CancelAfter(1000);
   try
   {
   ...
```

Теперь вопрос. В этой части кода

```
var canceletionToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
canceletionToken.CancelAfter(1000);
```

canceletionToken работает только для задачи, которая была запущена. Но если у нас есть полная очередь, запросы в этой очереди ждут долгое время. Я не могу придумать, как сделать таймер для элементов в очереди. Для запросов в очереди, ожидающих выполнения более 1 секунды, должно быть выброшено исключение.

Comment: вам нужен таймера и двунаправленной очередь

Comment: ну у меня canceletionToken вместо таймера

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795532/184217). Можете скооперироваться с его автором.

Comment: эм... я тут подумал... а чего имен вы хотите добиться? если просто ограничить кол-во обрабатываемых запросов и вдобавок сделать ограничение на время выполнения, то вы пошли не по верному пути(ну может и верному, но сложному). Очередь вам вообще не нужна.